# MPMoviePlayer not working properly

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a problem regarding to MPMoviePlayer. I am using `[self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];` to display player. When I click on Done button

```
(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification 
{    
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    // Remove observer
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                            object:nil];

    //[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
    //[self.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

method calls. When it navigates to previous view, previous view's x and y ordinates get disturbed and everything is changed, means, the view gets changed. Any suggestions ?

Comment: why is this code: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];        why are you trying to hide status bar?

Comment: but still one thing.. when I start video first time the Done button gets disappeared and second time its appeared !!! any solution ?

Comment: I guess you are taking about the auto hide feature. Can you please explain.

Comment: when I play the video first time "Done" button at left side is not visible but when I click on that position (where button should be displayed) all work fine and navigate to previous view. Next time when I play the same video the button gets visible !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by removing `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the methods [presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/UIViewController_MediaPlayer_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated%3a) and [dismisMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/UIViewController_MediaPlayer_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated%3a) instead of using `presentModalViewController:animated:` / `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`